# form display items php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a website that has a drop down menu which is coded like:

```
<form>
  <select name="languages">
    <option></option>
    <option value"html">HTML</option>
    <option value"css">CSS</option>
    <option value"js">JavaScript</option>
    <option value"csharp">C#</option>
    <option value"php">PHP</option>
    <option value"java">Java</option>
    <option value"phython">Phython</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
```

And in an ideal world, I'd want the relevent information to be displayed on the same page as the drop down menu. So when a user selects the `HTML` option, all the information for that will be displayed on the page, then if they choose the `PHP` option, the `HTML` information will be cleared and the `PHP` information will be loaded in.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Presumably you're looking at some form of AJAX that will allow you to make a call to a PHP script from Javascript within the webpage, and populate the page with information from the response. I'm not going to write the code for you, though.

Comment: all the information of "what" exactly?

Comment: You can use [jquery Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) codes with your own modifications as well as you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added some Jquery and CSS to your codes. Besides you forgot "=" in your value field. The solution is to get the value from select and use it to decide which Id has to be shown. Please run the code snippet and see the result.

```js
var id;
$("#languages").on("change",function(){
id=$(this).val();
$(".section").hide();
$("#"+id).stop().show();
})
```

```css
.section{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="languages" id="languages">
    <option></option>
    <option value="html">HTML</option>
    <option value="css">CSS</option>
    <option value="js">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="csharp">C#</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option>
    <option value="java">Java</option>
    <option value="phython">Phython</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
</form>

<div class="section" id="html">html content here</div>
<div class="section" id="css">CSS content here</div>
<div class="section" id="js">js content here</div>
<div class="section" id="csharp">csharp content here</div>
<div class="section" id="php">php content here</div>
<div class="section" id="java">java content here</div>
<div class="section" id="phython">phython content here</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)